# Meaning of double bracket "[[foo()]] type name;" syntax in c++?

Tags: c++, syntax, brackets

In [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/eliminate-false-sharing/217500206?pgno=4) article about avoiding False Sharing, the following code snipped for alignment is presented:

```
// C++ (using C++0x alignment syntax)
template<typename T>
struct cache_line_storage {
   [[ align(CACHE_LINE_SIZE) ]] T data;
   char pad[ CACHE_LINE_SIZE > sizeof(T)
        ? CACHE_LINE_SIZE - sizeof(T)
        : 1 ];
};
```

What is the meaning of line 4?
I've never seen this double bracket syntax before.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That is the [attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) specifier syntax. It was introduced as a unified syntax to access what were formerly compiler-specific extensions (now some are standardized).

In this case the code is telling the compiler to align `data` to `CACHE_LINE_SIZE` bytes.