# The meaning of double brackets after struct in C++?

Tags: c++

```
struct [[eosio::table("message"), eosio::contract("talk")]] message {
...
}
```

I googled a lot and no luck.

Could someone please explain:
What the meaning of double brackets `[[..]]` after struct in C++?

Comment: [look her](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451840/meaning-of-double-bracket-foo-type-name-syntax-in-c)

Comment: and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes

Comment: thank you all! I gave it a try and it seems a bit hard for non C++ person.
Any place with simpler explanation? eli5 style perhaps